# Count Repeat Visits from new visitors in the last year

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I need to count the number of repeat visits from members in the year 2015 from new members who joined in the year 2015.

```
SELECT
    playsite_id AS Loc, 
    DATENAME(MONT, date_id) AS Mon, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN visit_type = 'WALK-IN REPEAT' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) RepeatVisits,
    SUM(CASE WHEN visit_type = 'WALK-IN NEW' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NewVists
FROM 
    [dbo].[Guest_Visit_Fact]
WHERE
    visit_type IN ('WALK-IN REPEAT', 'WALK-IN NEW') 
    AND date_id >= '20150101' AND date_id < '20160101'
GROUP BY
    playsite_id, DATENAME(MONTH, date_id)
ORDER BY
    playsite_id
```

I am close. The repeat visits in this code returns all repeat visits in the year, but I only want repeat visits from NEW members who joined in that year. How can I do this?

I was thinking I could use WHERE NOT EXISTS. So if the ID existed before Jan 1, 2015, don't count it in the repeat visits column. I am just unsure how to code that. Thank you!

EDIT:

[image: here is what it should be].

The desired output should, theoretically, have a lower number of repeat visits than new visits (because we need the number of repeat visits FROM new visits for that year).

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Added in the edit above, thanks!

Comment: You still need to provide sample data and the schema